# Prove for any matrix $X$ that $C(X) \subseteq C(XX^{T})$ without using SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

My task is to prove for any matrix $X$ that $C(X)  \subseteq C(XX^{T})$ without using SVD, where $C(A)$ denotes the column space of matrix $A$. This may be accomplished by proving $$ x \in C(X) \implies x \in C(XX^{T})$$ After struggling with just chugging out the inner product mathematics, I thought I may be able to use proof by contrapositive and came up with this:

Suppose there exits a vector $ u \notin C(XX^{T})$, which is to say there exists no vector $v$ such that $$ u = XX^{T}v $$ We may write, however, $X^{T}v = b$ by simple matrix/vector multiplication. Thus, there exists no vector $b$ such that $$ u = Xb $$ Hence, $ u \notin C(X) $ by definition. Thus, $$ x \notin C(XX^{T}) \implies x \notin C(X)$$ which is equivalent to $$ x \in C(X) \implies x \in C(XX^{T})$$ by contraposition. QED

Are there faults in my reasoning, and if so how may I improve my proof or obtain the desired result by other means?

Comment: What is $C(X)$ ?

Comment: @Lelouch Sorry for not being clear. I edited the original post to clarify that $C(A)$ is the column space of matrix $A$.

Comment: It is more usual to say "range of $A$" instead of "column space of $A$"

Comment: The step "thus there exists no vector $b$ such that..." is incorrect. The correct statement is that there exists no $b$ *in the column space of $X^T$*. There may be some $b$ which is not in this column space. So you can't conclude that $x \not \in C(X)$ this way.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, that makes sense. Thank you for pointing that out. Do you have any ideas as to how else I may get the desired result?

Comment: Well, your argument never used at any point that $X^T$ was the transpose of $X$, so it couldn't possibly have worked. You need to actually use this hypothesis at some point so think about what an argument actually using this hypothesis could possibly look like.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extended hint where we just try to reason about what's happening at every step. I give away the first big step of the proof but not the second.

We want to show that if a vector $x$ can be written $x = Xw$ for some $w$, then it can be written $x = X X^T u$ for some $u$. If $X$ is invertible this is easy, since $X^T$ will also be invertible so we can just take $u = (X^T)^{-1} w$. More generally we are fine if $X^T$ is surjective. So the entire difficulty of the problem is that $X^T$ might not be surjective and we can't guarantee that $w$ lies in the image of $X^T$.

So what can we do about this? Well, if $x = Xw$ and also $x = X X^T u$, then subtracting gives $X(w - X^T u) = 0$, or equivalently $w - X^T u \in \text{Nul}(X)$. So if $X^T$ isn't surjective *and* $\text{Nul}(X) = 0$ then we're screwed. But we must not be screwed, so the assumption that $X^T$ isn't surjective must somehow imply that $\text{Nul}(X) \neq 0$, which would provide some room for us to find $u$ such that $w - X^T u \in \text{Nul}(X)$. In fact it does and this is why (here we actually use the assumption that $X^T$ is the transpose for the first time!):

> **Claim:** $\text{Nul}(X) = \text{Col}(X^T)^{\perp}$. That is, the nullspace $\{ v : Xv = 0 \}$ of $X$ is the orthogonal complement of the column space of $X^T$.

*Proof.* $Xv = 0$ iff $\langle v', Xv \rangle = 0$ for all $v'$ iff $\langle X^T v', v \rangle = 0$ for all $v'$ iff $v \in \text{Col}(X^T)^{\perp}$. $\Box$

Now we have the freedom to replace $w$ with another vector $w'$ such that $Xw = Xw'$, or equivalently such that $w - w' \in \text{Nul}(X) = \text{Col}(X^T)^{\perp}$. Now the question becomes: can we find a vector $w'$ such that

- $w - w' \in \text{Nul}(X) = \text{Col}(X^T)^{\perp}$, and
- $w' \in \text{Col}(X^T)$?

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I have been rereading since it was posted, I appreciate your help. I may have something now that works as a proof but I am not certain:

Proof: Suppose $x \in Col(X)$, i.e. there exists some vector $w$ s.t. $x = Xw$. Additionally, suppose that $w' \in Col(X^{T})$, i.e. $w' = X^{T}u$ for some vector $u$. Under the assumption that $X^{T}$ is not surjective, it must be true that $Nul(X) \neq 0$ since $Nul(X) = Col(X^{T})^{\perp}$. Thus we know $w-w' \in Nul(X)$, which is to say $X(w-X^{T}u) = 0$, or equivalently $x = Xw = XX^{T}u$. Therefore $x \in Col(X) \implies x \in Col(XX^{T})$. QED

Comment: @GoldMonkeyTMM: this doesn't make sense. You haven't specified where $u$ comes from so there's no reason we should have $w - w' \in \text{Nul}(X)$. You have to actually prove that such a $u$ exists with the desired properties, that's the remaining step.

Comment: Okay, if I specify that $u \in Nul(X)$ (i.e. $Xu = 0$) then I will have $w' = X^{T}u$ and so then with the previously specified $w$ we have $w-w' \in Nul(X)$, correct? I apologize if the answer is obvious and I am just completely missing something here, I am struggling but I think what I wrote may work.

Comment: @GoldMonkeyTMM: no, that doesn't follow at all. $Xu = 0$ isn't any help for showing that $w - X^T u \in \text{Nul}(X)$. It seems to me that you are not actually paying attention to the *meaning* of the symbols you're using, just hoping that some combination of symbols will happen to work. I suggest you try actually working with a specific example of a specific matrix, say $X = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{array} \right]$, and trying to show that for this *specific* matrix we have $\text{Col}(X) = \text{Col}(X X^T)$, by following the proof outline above.

Comment: I appreciate the help, the condescension not so much. I can assure you that I am not "just hoping that some combination of symbols will happen to work."

I can see for the provided specific matrix $X$ that $Col(X) = Col(XX^{T})$. To me it seems that the task at hand is to show that the vectors formed by the columns of $X$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors formed by the columns of $XX^{T}$. This is what I was trying to do earlier, before I had even written the original (incorrect) proof. Perhaps I should just return to that work.

Comment: My apologies. I'm just frustrated because you keep making unjustified steps and not noticing that you've done so; it's hard for me on this end to tell whether you understand the meaning of what you're writing because the unjustified step that doesn't make any sense looks exactly like everything else. Can you describe in your own words the last two corrections I made in these comments?

Comment: There is a genuine notational difficulty here I'm not sure how to deal with, which is that when we manipulate an expression like $w - X^T u$, $w$ and $X$ are both given but $u$ is unknown and has to be found. But the notation treats them all on equal footing. This is unfortunate but I'm really not sure how to be clear about what's going on without cluttering the notation.

Comment: @Yessuh: yes, but how do you know that fact about the rank? It's equivalent to the desired result.